# How to deal with modal controller outside AngularJs module?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

My app uses [Angular UI](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/0.13.0/) to deal with modals and I think I found a problem, as below:

I have a controller that calls the modal controller:

```
angular.module('MyApp').controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $modal) {
    $scope.openModal = function () {
        var myModal = $modal.open({
            animation: true,
            templateUrl: 'ModalContent.html',
            controller: ModalCtrl
        });
    };
});
```

I also have the modal controller in another file, as a simple function:

```
function ModalCtrl ($scope, $modalInstance) {
    $scope.ok = function () {
        $modalInstance.close();
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
};
```

It's working well, but I think the modal controller have to be inside AngularJs module. The questions are:

- Can I do it and keep the modal controller in a separated file?
- It's a good practice keep the modal controller outside AngularJs module?
- What is the best practice to reuse a modal controller in many pages?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That object you're passing into `$modal.open()` can be registered as a shared service and the modal controller can be embedded right inside it.

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('myModalConfig', function() {

    return {
        animation: true,
        templateUrl: 'ModalContent.html',
        controller: function($scope, $modalInstance) {
            $scope.ok = function () {
                $modalInstance.close();
            };

            $scope.cancel = function () {
                $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            };
        }
    };

});
```

Then just inject that along with the `$modal` service and pass it.

```
angular.module('MyApp').controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, myModalConfig) {
    $scope.openModal = function () {
        var myModal = $modal.open(myModalConfig);
    };
});
```

I go further than this myself and wrap the whole thing into a custom modal service factory, so I can just inject one thing and open modals like this: `profileModals.editProfile()`. But that's beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: And if I want to send dynamic parameters to $modal.open()? For example to change the modal title depending what controller called it

Comment: You could make the myModalConfig a factory function instead. `$modal.open(myModalConfig({title:"My Modal Title"}))` But the more of that you do the more you defeat the purpose of separating out the modal config into its own file.